# Displaying my content for two defined user groups

Tags: php, session, usergroups

I have two user groups - Admin (A) and Moderator (M) - and a navigation menu. Some of the links are only to be visible for the Admin, while the others are visible to both. Here's my current code:

```
<? if($_SESSION["LogedInAdminId"] && $_SESSION['AdminStatus']=="M") { ?>
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>

        <? if($_SESSION["LogedInAdminId"] && $_SESSION['AdminStatus']=="A") { ?>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
        <? { ?>

    </ul>
<? } ?>
```

Currently, the menu is only shown for moderators because of the first line:

```
<? if($_SESSION["LogedInAdminId"] && $_SESSION['AdminStatus']=="M") { ?>
```

So I tried to include the Admin group to is like so:

```
<? if($_SESSION["LogedInAdminId"] && $_SESSION['AdminStatus']=="M" || "A") { ?>
```

However, this breaks the code and displays the menu for everyone - Admin, Mod, guests, etc. What would be the correct way of including two user groups?

Comment: Firstly make sure the session was started. Now this `|| "A"` you need to add a new condtion, you can't just use it like that. You can also use an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, make sure the [session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) was started for all pages using sessions.

Now this syntax `|| "A"` isn't correct. You need to add a new condition.

Here's what you need to do, and bracketing the second condition:

```
if( $_SESSION["LogedInAdminId"] 
    && ($_SESSION['AdminStatus']=="M" || $_SESSION['AdminStatus']=="A")
  )
```

Comment: Ahh, I see... so the `||` does work in this case, I just used it incorrectly. Thank so much, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

you have to combine you user groups like this to check if the `AdminStatus` is **M** OR (||) **A**

```
<? if($_SESSION["LogedInAdminId"] && ($_SESSION['AdminStatus']=="M" || $_SESSION['AdminStatus']=="A")) { ?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.